# ReflectionClass::newInstance/newInstanceArgs generates undefined property

Tags: php

When I try to create a new instance with constructor arguments via the `ReflectionClass` object I get this notice:

> Notice: Undefined property: ReflectionClass::$newInstanceArgs in XXX on line 93

On line 93 I simply try to instanciate the reflection by:

```
$obj = new $reflection->newInstanceArgs([$arg1]);
```

The notice is generated by newInstance as well:

```
$obj = new $reflection->newInstance([$arg1]);
```

> Notice: Undefined property: ReflectionClass::$newInstance in XXX on line 93

The class I'm trying to instantiate looks like this:

```
class ObjectName
{
      public function __construct ($str = "")
      {}
}
```

I can't seem to find the problem. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an excess `new`. The `newInstance{,Args}` [reflectionclass.newinstance](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php) function already instantiates and returns an instance for you. Try: `$obj = $reflection->newInstance([..]);`

Comment: Explanation, what's going on: the parser recognizes `new CLASS_NAME(ARGUMENTS)` and then tries to resolve CLASS_NAME to `$reflection->newInstanceArgs` - now this would be a property, not a method.